# No output from sed when grouping with multiple parentheses

Tags: regex, sed

I have this sed expression to replace the output with the actual match of the regex expression:

`$( sed -n 's/.*\((http|https):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)*\).*/\1/pg' < access-medium.log )`

Input:

`66.249.76.98 - - [12/Aug/2016:06:26:33 +0200] "GET /kod-exempel/dynamic_php_menu/ HTTP/1.1" 301 3859 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`

Desired output:

`http://www.google.com`
or
`https://www.google.com`

I use *\ before and after expression to replace
with nothing and then I print the line, what am I missing here?

Comment: It is POSIX BRE pattern, so escape the capturing parentheses and alternation operator. Also, you are replacing with `1`, are you sure you do not need `\1`?

Comment: Corrected the 1, but the most outer ( ) which signifies group 1 is escaped already is it not? `\( \)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a POSIX BRE pattern (no `-E` nor `-r` used), so you need to remember that capturing parentheses and alternation operator (with GNU `sed` in mind) must be escaped.

You can use

```
sed -n 's~.*\(https\{0,1\}://[^/]*\).*~\1~p'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/UiiJrZ)

**Details**

- `-n` - option suppressing default line output
- `.*\(https\{0,1\}://[^)]*\).*` - regex pattern matching

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars
  - `\(https\{0,1\}://[^/]*\)` - Group 1: `http`, and optional `s`, `://`, then zero or more chars other than `/`
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `\1` - replacement is the Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Comment: Trying to understand this with my original regex and without the -E option.
This is what I have now (escaping all parantheses and special chars):
`$( sed -n  's/.*\(\(http\|https\):\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\)*\).*/\1/pg' < access-medium.log )`

Comment: @ollebergkvist First, remove `g` flag, there will only be 1 replacement. In a POSIX ERE regex, escape literal parentheses, not capturing ones. Also, your URL regex does not match `/`, see [fixed code](https://ideone.com/JsOmfi).

Comment: I realized I put a faulty desired output, it should be without / hence my original regex. Trying this now.

Comment: I appreciate the help here! But the refactoring of my original regex is not helping me understand. I'm just getting into regex and sed and currently my commands are very long and intriguing and I need to make things work with this in mind.

Comment: @ollebergkvist Then it is even easier, see updated answer.

Comment: It works, still need to figure it out how to make my original regex work though :)) Why do you use "~" over "/", tried to replace with "/" and then I get unknown option to s?

Comment: @ollebergkvist `~` is a better delimiter here since it allows to use `/` without escaping it in the pattern.